# Why do I receive a warning about an assembly reference that appears to be identical in version and culture

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, mono

I am using Xamarin on a Mac and have built up a series of .netstandard1.3 libraries. One of which is referencing a few external packages:

1. NETStandard.Library
2. Newtonsoft.Json
3. System.Linq.Queryable
4. System.Reactive
5. System.Security.Principal

When I build the project (library) it builds but with the following warning:

> /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/4.8.1/lib/mono/xbuild/14.0/bin/Microsoft.CSharp.targets (CoreCompile target) ->
>
> CSC:  warning CS1702: Assuming assembly reference
>   `System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, Version=4.1.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' matches assembly`
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives, Version=4.1.1.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. 
>   You may need to supply runtime policy

I'm not directly referencing this specific library anywhere, but even if I were the version and public key token appear to be identical so why the complaint? How do I get rid of this warning and why am I getting it?

Comment: I'm having a similar issue in a Xamarin.Forms project, just with a different assembly reference. Looking forward to seeing how this develops.

Comment: @Jonathan not that this is a solution, but I've recently changed all of my pre-existing projects from 1.3 net standard to 2.0 (a new project type required for this) and this seems to have removed this issue, and indeed the need for a lot of the extraneous references.

Answer (score 0):

Despite having the same assembly identity, there are different implementations of `System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll` presumably because of runtime specific behavior / implementation. MSBuild is not sure which to use. You may target your library to multiple runtimes, or distribute it as a NuGet package which shifts the responsibility of picking a target runtime to the library or app consuming your package. You can download the package, change it to a `.zip` and take a peak inside to see what I mean.